# adb processcan't be killed

Tags: eclipse, process, sdk, adb

even I killed the adb (android AVD manager ) with the following command:

```
pkill adb
```

I still got the adb running

`~/.android$ pkill adb
~/.android$ ps aux | grep adb
1000      3849  0.0  0.0  13628   940 pts/1    S+   18:26   0:00 grep --color=auto adb`

why I can't kill it?

---

I tried also with this command:

`~/.android$ adb shell kill 3849
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found`

I don't understand why he mentioned **"device not found"**!!!!

I just want to stop the AVD processs to get my eclipse turn well back

**************It's solved**************

**I just made an update and I removed the .android directory**
thanks to Zac Lozano who passed me this useful link :http://www.androiddevelopercenter.com/eclipse-and-android-error-parsesdkcontent-failed/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a last measure type answer, but the nuclear option seemed to work for this fellow:

http://www.androiddevelopercenter.com/eclipse-and-android-error-parsesdkcontent-failed/

What I would try rather than deleting stuff is switch workspaces, and install a fresh android plugin, and be sure your android sdk environment variable is pointing to your sdk home.

Comment: I got this 
`bash: kill: (3849) - Aucun processus de ce type`

Comment: oups sorry I forgot translating it:
it's ` no process with that type`

Comment: From your ps aux output, it looks like 3849 belongs to your grep program (on the far right of the output line) which would've already terminated by the time you sent the SIGINT, hence the no such process message.  You need to find the process ID for adb

Comment: If that is the only output you get from running ps aux | grep adb, then most likely adb in fact has been killed.  What you see there is the process id for grep.  It matched since you looked for 'adb' and it has 'adb' at the very end.  Is there any other indication that adb may be running?

Comment: since this morning I passed by this error because I couldn't run the AVD from eclipse or through the terminal,eclipse can't located the SDK directory.this is what eclipse shows me while starting it

`/parseSdkContent failed
com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(Lcom/android/sdklib/repository/local/LocalSdk;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/internal/avd/AvdManager;`

I thought that sdk problem came from the AVD process

Comment: I know this is a last measure type answer, but the nuclear option seemed to work for this fellow: http://www.androiddevelopercenter.com/eclipse-and-android-error-parsesdkcontent-failed/

What I would try rather than deleting stuff is switch workspaces, and install a fresh android plugin, and be sure your android sdk environment variable is pointing to your sdk home.

Comment: thanks @Zac :))) 
I fixed it finally
I just made an update and removed the .android directory
works like a charm

Comment: Great! In order to help others with the same issue in the future, maybe you could edit the original question since it currently does not reflect the actual issue.  I will update my answer as well with the link to the solution.